# 64bits desktop does not boot

Tags: boot

My 64bits desktop (intel core i7) was able to boot with Windows XP 64 installed, but it's not more possible after installing Ubuntu amd64: the computer says the HD is not bootable. The only way of booting the computer now, is using the Live CD and choosing boot from the hard disk. Besides, if I put this HD in a 32bits computer, grub boots normally. How can I enable boot directly from the HD using the 64bits desktop?

Comment: Did you really mean that you have an intel cpu and installed an amd distribution? I'm not sure this is a bad idea but it sounds like it could cause problems.

Comment: @msw: "amd64" stands for "x86-64" and simply means "64-bit". It has nothing to do with the processor's vendor.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sdX` (replace X with the right letter for your hard disk - see the above linked guide, if you don't know how to find out).

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure :)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to reinstall grub (or at least have it embedded on the MBR). Grub does usually work fine in a 64bit environment (at least it works here).

There are a lot of guides out there for doing this but most concern Grub v1. Ubuntu has been on Grub v2 (confusingly the actual version number is 1.9x) for a while and the repair instructions are slightly different.

If I were you, I'd follow [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling%20from%20LiveCD) and see where you get.

Comment: I'll follow your suggestion with the guide, but I've already tried the SIMPLEST method and I was unable to solve it. Also, I tried to restore mbr using "fixboot /mbr" with a Windows installation CD and nothing happened. However, in a 32bits computer, everything proceeds as expected. Is there a possibility of a bug in the firmware of the BIOS?

Comment: `fixboot` will kill `grub`. It's possible a BIOS firmware issue. What's the motherboard?

Comment: Right, fixboot will kill grub (mbr) and this was the intention as the original configuration (with Windows XP 64) was booting ok. It was just a try to see if the computer boots with a mbr from Windows, but it was not. Weird!

Comment: The motherboard is an Intel DX58SO.

Comment: Here a user successfully installed Ubuntu 8.10 x64 on the Intel DX58SO: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/317607

Comment: @Vitor is the BIOS up to date?

Comment: The actual BIOS version is 02/10/2009 (mm/dd/yyyy) and the last one is 08/30/2010. On the release note, I could notice many fixes about boot and an upgrade in BIOS might be a solution. But this is actually a server and I'd like to avoid BIOS upgrade if possible.
http://downloadmirror.intel.com/19271/eng/SO_5417_ReleaseNotes.pdf

Comment: I wish my BIOS updates came with this much detail! I don't see the server argument, personally. It's firmware-upgradable hardware like any other. They've issued fixes and if anything, that's more of an argument to apply it than not because it could contain fixes that fix this issue. If you're stoically against installing upgrading the BIOS, the only solution I see available is installing grub on another disk (eg a USB stick) and having that chainload through to your real disk (much like the CD does now). It's much dirtier than a BIOS upgrade but it might work.

Comment: I also see several performance improvements in the changelog too.

Comment: But he was able to use Win XP 64 before, why would the BIOS suddenly complain about the disk not being bootable? The only thing left I can think of, is that the BIOS requires a partition with the boot flag set and there is none. Again, the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sdX` would be nice to have.

Answer (score 1):

Just saw the line:

> I put this HD in a 32bits computer, grub boots normally

That (paired with it booting from the CD) suggests that your BIOS is looking at the wrong drive to boot. Check that this disk is the primary boot device.

Comment: Agree, that would also explain why he can boot the installation via the live CD.

Comment: I checked the boot order (HD first), and also chose manually to boot from the HD. In both cases, if there is no CD inside, I receive the message "The drive is not bootable"; if there is the CD, it proceeds to boot the Live CD normally.

Comment: @Vitor Then there might be something messed up with grub. Work through the grub restoration guide in my other post.

Comment: Just to add information, I installed grub many times as a consequence of installing Debian 5.0 amd64, Ubuntu 9.04 amd65, Kubuntu 9.10 and Kubuntu 10.10 amd64. None of the installations allowed me to boot in the 64bits desktop, but just in a 32bits.

Answer (score 0):

Following my last comment, I googled for your motherboard and "boot flag", and in fact the Intel DX58SO doesn't boot, if there is no primary partition with the boot flag set.

You can check this with:

`fdisk -l /dev/sdX`

If no partition has an asterix (*) in the 'boot.' column, then that's the problem.

To fix this, you can use GParted from the live CD:

- Right click any primary partition
- Select 'Manage Flags'
- Tick the 'boot' flag
- Click on 'Close'

You're done.

Comment: Ok. I didn't put the result of the command yet because the server is running Windows and it cannot be stopped at this moment. I'll check this as soon as possible.

Comment: /dev/sda5   *       58337       60693    18932571   83  Linux

My logical /dev/sda5 partition has an asterix, and is where Linux is installed. But there still exist the possibility of BIOS needing a primary partition with boot flag, instead of a logical one.

Comment: And I'll have to wait some more weeks to perform this test.

Comment: The [page where I found this](http://translate.google.de/translate?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linux-community.de%2FInternal%2FArtikel%2FOnline-Artikel%2FSechs-Kerne-sollt-ihr-sein%2F%28printView%29%2Ftrue&sl=de&tl=en&hl=&ie=UTF-8) (German -> English translation) explicitly stated it needs a primary partition with the boot flag set. Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try a nifty software called boot repair from any thing that boots and try to manage all the os from there.Be it MBR or grub

Just have a try

Comment: Providing a link would be helpful. [Here's the community documentation link to boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)